# How do I get the minimum value of two CGFloats in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat

I have this code that should return the minimum value of two `CGFloat` values:

```
    var boundsSize:CGSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var imageSize:CGSize = imageView.bounds.size

    var xScale:CGFloat = boundsSize.width / imageSize.width
    var yScale:CGFloat = boundsSize.height / imageSize.height

    var minScale:CGFloat = MIN(xScale, yScale) // this does not work
```

But `MIN` does not seem to have an equivalent in swift. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var minScale = min(xScale, yScale)
```

`min` is already in swift. Hope this helps.. :)

`min` is variadic function. Its reset parameter is a variadic parameter. From developer site:

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type. You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be passed a varying number of input values when the function is called. Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (...) after the parameter’s type name.

For more info. [See this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Comment: the function signature is `func min<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T` - what is the rest parameter?

Comment: It's a variadic function, you don't need to pass anything there.

Answer (score 4):

The function in Swift is `min`, so:

`var minScale = min(xScale, yScale)`